# How to colorize rows in ag-grid/angular using gridOptions?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to colorize rows based on their rank. I found-out that I have to use gridOptions. But, I have failed to use it propertly.
This is what I've done so far:
In the html file:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  style="width: 5000px ; height: 1000px;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [rowData]="rowDataBia"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefsBia"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

In the component, this is the relevant code:

```
 private gridOptions: GridOptions;

  gridOptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return { background: 'red' }
    }
}
```

As I said this doesn't work.
Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and maybe how to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 gridOptions: GridOptions;

  this.gridOptions.getRowStyle = (params) => {
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return { background: 'red' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a simple solution:
In the grid definition in the html file add this:

```
[getRowStyle]="getRowStyle"
```

In the typescript file add this:

```
    public getRowStyle = function(params){
    if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
      return { background: 'red' }
  }
  }
```